# RecycleView does not retrieve data from Google Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need help with `RecycleView` in Kotlin. I have my Google Firestore connected, and all my CRUD operations are working. Now I want to view those created movie `Titles` I add to Firebase, but the `RecycleView` is not showing me anything of my Firestore data.

**NewestTitlesFragment:**

```
package com.example.watchlist.sampledata

class NewestTitlesFragment : Fragment() {

    private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    private val db:FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val collectionReference:CollectionReference = db.collection("users").document(currentUser!!.uid).collection("titles")

    var titleAdapter: TitleAdapter? = null

    lateinit var binding: FragmentNewestTitlesBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) =FragmentNewestTitlesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).run {
        binding = this
        val query : Query = collectionReference
        val firestoreRecyclerOptions: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Watch> = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Watch>()
            .setQuery(query, Watch::class.java)
            .build()

        titleAdapter = TitleAdapter(firestoreRecyclerOptions)
        newestTitlesRecycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        newestTitlesRecycleView.adapter = titleAdapter

        root
    }

}
```

**TitleAdapter:**

```
    package com.example.watchlist
    
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
    import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions
    
    
    class TitleAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Watch>) :
        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Watch, TitleAdapter.TitleAdapterVH>(options) {
        
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TitleAdapterVH {
            return TitleAdapterVH(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.titles_layout, parent, false))
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TitleAdapterVH, position: Int, model: Watch) {
    
            holder.movieTitle.text = model.title
    
        }
    
        class TitleAdapterVH(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    
            var movieTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.movieTitle)
            var moviePoster = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.titlePoster)
        }
    }
```

**Watch:**

```
    package com.example.watchlist
    
    import android.net.Uri
    
    data class Watch(
        val id : Int,
        var title :String ,
        var content:String,
        var date:String,
        var img:String ,
        )
```

**titles_layout.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/titlePoster"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_newest_titles.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FAF7F7"
        tools:context=".sampledata.NewestTitlesFragment">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/newestTitlesRecycleView"
                android:background="#000000"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/watchlist_logo" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Newest Titles"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/newestTitlesRecycleView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#8A8A8A"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Change this line holder.movieTitle.text = model.title to holder.movieTitle.text = model.get(position).title

Comment: it didnt help, i changed holder.movieTitle.text = model.title to holder.movieTitle.text = model.get(position).title and it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

These types of issues can be hard to diagnose without understanding the environment you are using. It is better to test locally as much as possible and review any error logs produced during the deployment process.

There are some excellent tools to test your Firebase code locally. If you [unit test](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) your code incrementally and [interactively from a local shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell), you will identify any issues quickly.

You can also use the [Firebase Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to prototype, develop and test your code before moving it to production.